# Все до одних... выборы?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Элементы - это множество, где составляющая - это элемент. Поэтому говорится "...**все до одного элементы** были найдены...". До одного - имеется ввиду элемента.

**Вопрос:** А как будет с выборами, например, президентскими, за все периоды? Выборы в данном примере (за все периоды) - это множество, где составляющая - это другие выборы.

Будет верно "**все до одних выборы**"? "**Все до одного выборы**" звучит странно.

Answer (score 1):

*"Все до одних"* звучит не менее странно, к тому же в Нацкорпусе нет ни одного примера с таким словосочетанием.
По-видимому, этот фразеологизм просто лексически не сочетается с существительными, не употребляющимися в единственном числе.
Придётся перестроить фразу так, чтобы фразеологизм относился к другому слову, например: *"Все до одного случаи президентских выборов..."* (Не слишком удачно тут *"случаи"*, но это просто пример.)